# How can I accept a list of Func<> delegates and return a list of list when the List of func<> processes different objects

Tags: c#, generics, list

Following is my code where, I am passing a stored procedure as SQL to execute which runs *multiple Select statements*. Now the output of each datareader.NextResult() would be a different object (A POCO class) and they will not be dependent (hence I can't have an interface/base class to access them). The problem with this approach is that I have to do typecasting on the list returned by SelectQuery. Is there a better way to achieve following so that I can avoid typecasting?

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SelectQuery<T>(string strSql, List<Func<IDataRecord, T>> infoExtractors)
{
  var result = new List<List<T>>();

  using (var connection = GetDBConnection())
  {
    using (var command = GetDBCommand(strSql))
    {
      command.Connection = connection;
      connection.Open();
      using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
      {
        try
        {
          int i = 0;
          List<T> curList = new List<T>();
          result.Add(curList);
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            curList.Add(infoExtractors[i](reader));
          }

          while(reader.NextResult())
          {
            i++;
            curList = new List<T>();
            result.Add(curList);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              curList.Add(infoExtractors[i](reader));
            }
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          reader.Close();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

*The primary purpose of this code is to avoid letting caller closing the DB connection*

Following is a sample code I wrote to simulate this and check if I can avoid typecasting

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      List<Func<int, object>> lst = new List<Func<int, object>>();      
      lst.Add(c1.SetThis);      
      lst.Add(c2.SetThis);
      lst.Add(c3.SetThis);
      var output=  Check(lst);


      foreach(var cur in output)
      {
        foreach(var innerCur in cur)
        {
          System.Console.Write(innerCur);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
      }
      System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static List<List<T>> Check<T>(List<Func<int, T>> inpList) 
    {
      List<List<T>> lst = new List<List<T>>();

      lst.Add(new List<T>() { inpList[0](10) });
      lst.Add(new List<T>() { inpList[1](20) });
      lst.Add(new List<T>() { inpList[2](30) });

      return lst;
    }


  }

  class c1
  {
    internal int num;

    internal static c1 SetThis(int i)
    {
      c1 c1Obj= new c1();
      c1Obj.num = i;
      return c1Obj;
    }
  }

  class c2
  {
    internal int num;
    internal static c2 SetThis(int i)
    {
      c2 c2Obj = new c2();
      c2Obj.num = i;
      return c2Obj;
    }
  }

  class c3
  {
    internal int num;
    internal static c3 SetThis(int i)
    {
      c3 c3Obj = new c3();
      c3Obj.num = i;
      return c3Obj;
    }
  }
```

Now, although the test sample has the same methodname, the classes c1,c2, c3 in reality will hold different data. Also The **inner foreach loop for innerCur** prints the type but I need a way to get the value without using typecasting? IS it possible? In worst case I will have to get rid of following inner foreach

```
foreach(var innerCur in cur)
{
  System.Console.Write(innerCur);
}
```

with

```
 foreach (var innerCur in cur)
 {
   if(innerCur is c1)
      System.Console.Write((innerCur as c1).num);
   else if(innerCur is c2)
      System.Console.Write((innerCur as c2).num);
   else
      System.Console.Write((innerCur as c3).num);
 }
```

Comment: *"The primary purpose of this code is to avoid letting caller closing the DB connection*": why would you do that?

Comment: I am developing a library and I do not want to return the DataReader to the caller which may result in DB connection being open for more than necessary time (say user is processing data and doing some calculations while reading). I want to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: have a look at the tuple class which has mutiple generic types. I think you might need to make a differnt class for each number of tables though. Ie result<T1,T2,T3.. etc

Comment: @Ewan It does make the method little better and I would not need typecasting if I use Tuple<T1,T2,...> but then it will require me to define Check<T1,T2...>() method for number of times with increasing number of input parameters. I can surely get the same result I get using Tuple by passing out parameters but then it will be great if I need not define a method with 1 parameter, 2 parameter, 3 parameters ...

Comment: yeah its not perfect. Not sure if what you attempting is possible. Remember generics compile to specific classes and you want to be able to pass the class to compile to in at run time

Comment: I think you can do it with releflection though. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: I tried that but IMHO it complicates the things as compared to simple typecasting and I am not sure if I should expect the users of my library to use reflection to fetch data?

Comment: Your api can return whatever you want, just make it implement ´IDisposable´. You won't expose implementation details, but it's pretty common for ORM libraries to return "sessions", which manage the lifetime of a connection. Also, keep in mind that connections can be pooled in .NET, making their cost lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting problem. The only solution I can think of is to use reflection inside your Generic Repository class to call methods on the generic Type which has been passed in.

This gets around the problem by having the consumer of the library write a class which matches the DataBase and Tables they are querying, including the functions which transform the datarow into their object AND the List which is populated by that function.

The user passes this object into the GetData method and it becomes populated by the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThierCode
{
    public class MyTableQuery : YourLibrary.IMultiTableQuery
    {

        public Dictionary<string, string> MethodNameAndSql { get; set; }

        public void PopulateMyObjects(IDataRecord dr)
        {
            MyObject o = new MyObject();
            o.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            this.MyObjects.Add(o);
        }

        public List<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace YourLibrary
{
    public interface IMultiTableQuery
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> MethodNameAndSql { get; set; }
    }
    public class Repo<T> where T : IMultiTableQuery
    {
        public void GetData(T inputClass)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);


            foreach (var kvp in inputClass.MethodNameAndSql)
            {
                string sql = kvp.Value;
                //run sql and get datareader

                //get the populate method back from the dictionary 
                MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(kvp.Key);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // execute via reflection
                    methodInfo.Invoke(inputClass, reader);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```